# AWS Lambda triggers SNS on DynamoDB table changes

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm trying to write a lambda function that gets's triggered by any changes to a dynamoDB table, and send browser push notification through SNS which will be invoked by the Lambda, what are good practices to achieve this functionality? AWS documentation lacks details, can someone point to a tutorial or repo that explains how to structure such service?

Answer (score 6):

I think the exact use case you are describing is covered by the [DynamoDB Streams Use Cases](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) blog article. Scroll down to the **Notifications/messaging** section.

For the push notification part, that should be pretty straightforward via the [SNS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html).

Comment: Thank you now i'm able to trigger the lambda and send an email with dynamoDB changes for subscribed users, but how can I let a user subscribe from UI I mean from angular through a radio button?

Comment: That sounds like a different question now, maybe best asked with an Angular tag. Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 4):

Now you can trigger AWS SNS without Lambda using EventBridge Pipes (re:invent 2022). This can trigger SNS notification with DynamoDB table change.

DynamoDB Streams --> EventBridge Pipes --> AWS SNS.

No need for Lambda code to trigger SNS now.

For more details, you can read this blog - https://medium.com/@moitrasayan007/triggering-aws-sns-with-dynamodb-streams-without-lambda-with-eventbridge-pipes-9d8f1a9aa209